# AWS Glue python install - Could not find a version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to use the AWSGlue module in Python, but cannot install the module in the terminal.

```
sh-4.2$ pip install awsglue
Collecting awsglue
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awsglue (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awsglue
```

Is there a way around this or is there a way I can download this from a third-party?

Does anyone have this AWSGlue module working?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the `awsglue` package is only available in the images provided by AWS.
So you'll need to download their image and run it, then `awsglue` is available in the global namespace.

Annoying, yes I know.